# I need combine indexs of a tuple how can i do this

Tags: python

I was trying a bigger letter to the index of word i did it but it is not in the same of index

```
k = 'kars'
k = k[0].upper(),k[1],k[2],k[3],k[4]
```

it is distributing the letters how can i combine them

Comment: `k` and `k[0]` are both type `str` so add them:   `k = k[0].upper() + k[1:]`. I recommend to close this question as it is duplicate and doesn't show a significant effort to do your own research so is likely to be down-voted per the normal usage of stack overflow just FYI.

Comment: `k[4]` results in an `IndexError`

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [`title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method:

```
k = 'kars'
print(k.title())
# OR
print(k[0].upper() + k[1:])
# OR
def uppercaseAtIndex(k, i):
    newK = list(k)
    newK[i] = newK[i].upper()
    return ''.join(newK)


print(uppercaseAtIndex(k, 1))
```

Out:

```
Kars
Kars
kArs
```

Comment: I want any index not 0th index

Comment: @Luwem: What do you mean ? You want `KARS` ?

Comment: kArs or kaRs , karS and too much. I want whatever i want of a index

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator expression and enumerate to capitalize a specific index. Join the letters with str.join().

```
index = 1
''.join(letter.upper() if i==index else letter for i,letter in enumerate('thestring'))
```